# "Explain to me" questions are not on-topic here

Tags: feature-request, about-faq

The following passage from the Skeptics FAQ has always bothered me:

> However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain **__** to me”, then you are probably OK.

While that's perfectly acceptable for other Stack Exchange sites, I don't think it is here. Simply put, we verify rather than explain. I don't think a single “I would like others to explain **__** to me” type of question would ever fall as on-topic. Therefore, that section of the FAQ is misleading.

Can something be done about this?

Answer (score 3):

How about the simple change of "explain __ to me" to "explain *what the evidence says about* __ to me" which changes the focus from the *claim* to understanding the *evidence* about the claim.