# Are political questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, politics

For example, "What's the real reason Bush attack Iraq?" or "Why people are religious?

Answer (score 6):

If a politician makes a specific claim that is in the realm of science? Yes.

If it is about the "real" motivations of a person? [No](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/887#887), that can't be meaningfully answered.

The question "Why are people religious?" is, as it stands, off-topic. There is no claim, it is just a general question. [Issue discussed here.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/explain-to-me-questions-are-not-on-topic-here)

---

The basic template isn't that hard: **Find someone notable, or lots of people, who said something you suspect might be wrong, and quote them, with a link back to where they said it.** There are variations to that template, but it is a pretty good start.

Common mistakes:

- Not quoting anyone.
- Making up your own quote.
- Quoting someone you are sure is right.
- Quoting someone who is saying something unfalsifiable.
- Quoting someone who gives lots of evidence to support their statement, unless you have some reason to doubt it.