# Why is this question closed and yet similar questions are okay?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6964/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-regarding-measurable-adverse-effects-if-any-o

A simmilar question is not

[Does child rearing by homosexual couples have any measurable negative effects?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-regarding-measurable-adverse-effects-if-any-o)

Notable claim - check! Just look at the pictures attached. Also I've heard poor indian parents would cut the limbs of their children to improve begging skills. Those looks like adverse effects to me.

Comment: Now the question is erased. Gee... why?

Answer (score 3):

**Why was the question closed?**

Because the question did not demonstrate the notability described in the answers to your [previous meta-question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1228/is-political-questions-within-scientific-realms-permitted/1229#1229)

You did not quote a statement from someone that you were skeptical about.

> I mean do poor people tend to have poorer kids?

Do you doubt this claim? Is anyone making the *opposite* claim? If not, it is out-of-scope.

**Why was the question deleted?**

I wasn't the one who took the action, but I would hazard: It is because when you were challenged to provide notability, instead you took pot-shots at the moderators and added (somewhat distressing) photographs of poverty - these were completely irrelevant to the question - no-one is denying serious poverty exists. The question appeared irredeemable.

**Why wasn't the same-sex parents question closed?**

Because it was *such* a notable claim, that everyone involved *had* heard some variant of it (e.g. "A child needs a mother and a father." or [Ref](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110104140417AA9gVpw)) and the author was (quite reasonably) skeptical about that claim.

p.s. If you do add images, don't forget to provide references.

Comment: Oh I see. So a question is a notable claim if the OPPOSITE claim is also notable. Is that what you're saying? I can't ask, "Is water liquid?". Is that what you're saying?

Comment: No, I do not think I am saying that first sentence. I am saying there needs to be someone making a claim that you are dubious about. Nobody is dubious that poor people tend to have poor children. No conflict = no motivation. Some people believe that same-sex parents are detrimental to the welfare of the children, and some are dubious, so there is something worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment section, it's not a notable claim.

Comment: I thought the question is closed because it's too obvious. Notable claim? Just look at this https://www.google.com/search?q=poverty&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1342&bih=331&sei=XyHCToqhEYuTiQeQw7ncDQ

Comment: http://parenting.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/09/20/are-poor-parents-poorer-at-parenting/ also rich dad poor dad is a book that are made under the assumption that richer dad tend to educate their kids better. I want to add more reference to show that this is a notable claim but the question is already deleted?