# Are opposite claims need to be notable too?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions like is water liquid, etc? Sometimes some questions may seem to be too obvious.

However, unless I can point a link to a sceptic side, most would think find holes.

[Why is this question closed and yet similar questions are okay?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/why-is-this-question-closed-and-yet-similar-questions-are-okay)

Comment: I think "**Don't waste our time**" pretty much sums it up.

Comment: I suggest you just observe for a while (perhaps a few weeks?) to get a feel for the types of questions and answers that are common around here before posting further questions or answers -- your most recent question (http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/is-this-true-that-no-women-can-consent-to-prostitution) featured a link to sexual images of naked people instead of questioning a notable claim, which really doesn't suit this web site.

Answer (score 4):

I fear I am wasting my time answering this, but here goes.

I do not understand your point: Why would you ask "Is water liquid?"

Either you meant to come up with a question that was obviously true? Like the traditional "Is the Pope Catholic?" or the one about the bear and the woods. Or you meant to come up with a trick question.

If you meant to come up with an obviously true question like "Is the Pope Catholic?" question, then **NO** you shouldn't be asking that question. If no-one has any reason to doubt it, why would we be wasting out time on it? For that matter, why would *you* waste *your* time asking it? Find an issue where someone is making a statement that you suspect could be wrong.

If you meant to be coming up with some trick question where the answer is "No" - because water is NOT always liquid; it is sometimes a gas or a solid (a.k.a. steam or ice) - then the answer is still **NO** you shouldn't be asking that question. Because there is no-one who is deliberating claiming that water is always a liquid and never a solid or a gas. So, again, why should we spend any time trying to resolve an issue where no-one is wrong?

So, whatever your original intent, the question "Is water liquid?" is off-topic.

> However, unless I can point a link to a sceptic side, most would think find holes.

I am very sorry, but I cannot understand what you meant by this sentence.